# Prove that $g(z)=\overline{f(z)}$ is complex diﬀerentiable at $a$ if and only if $f'(a) = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$, and let $g : \Omega →
> > \mathbb{C}$ be given by $g(z) = \overline{f(z)}$. Prove that $g$ is
>   complex diﬀerentiable at $a$ if and only if $f'(a) = 0$.

I have tried the basic limit definition for derivatives but couldn't come up with a proper solution. 
Also I know that for a complex valued function $f=u+iv$, If $u$ and $v$ have continuous first derivatives, then $f$ should be analytic on $\Omega$. But I'm not exactly sure whether it will be useful here.

Hep would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the Cauchy Riemann equalities applied to $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
So that means, Holomorphic nature of $f$ implies $u_x=v_y$ and differentiability of $g$ implies $u_x=-v_y$. Thus $u_x=0$. And from the limit definition we have 
$f'(a)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Hence it is zero

Am I correct?

Comment: But what about the other side of the implication?

Comment: Oh I see. 
In the same way from the bottom we can argue that the partial derivatives are equal to zero. Thus they are continuously differentiable!

Comment: This is not correct, because the fact that a point is a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations is not enough to assure that the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: Hi Jose. But if the partial derivatives are continuous and if they are satisfied, can't we say that the function is differentiable

Comment: @CharithJeewantha How do you know that the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: mmm.. I think we can get it from, the $f'(a)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ which says all the partial derivatives are zero

Answer (score 3):

If $f'(a)=w\neq0$, then\begin{align}\lim_{z\to a}\frac{g(z)-g(a)}{z-a}&=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(a)}}{z-a}\\&=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(a)}}{\overline z-\overline a}\times\frac{\overline z-\overline a}{z-a}\end{align}and this limit doesn't exist, because $\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(a)}}{\overline z-\overline a}=\overline w\neq0$ and the limit $\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline z-\overline a}{z-a}$ doesn't exist. So, $g$ is not diferentiable at $a$.

On the other hand, if $f'(a)=0$, then$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\overline{f(z)}-\overline{f(a)}}{\overline z-\overline a}\times\frac{\overline z-\overline a}{z-a}=0,$$as it is the product of something that goes to $0$ with a bounded function. Therefore, $g'(a)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. So it covers both the implications right?

Comment: Yes, it sure does.